# Why won't my QFileDialog load its directory or apply filters?

Tags: python, pyside2

I've made a QFileDialog as per the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtWidgets/QFileDialog.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName):

```
self.ui.load_configuration = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Load Configuration", f"{os.getcwd()}/configurations", "*.cf")
```

For some reason the dialog opens up in the home directory and does not apply the ".cf" filter. However, when I instead make this save file dialog:

```
self.ui.load_configuration = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Load Configuration", f"{os.getcwd()}/configurations", "*.cf")
```

The directory opens as expected, but the filter does not work.

Comment: What OS are you on? What happens if you use the non-native file dialog? Try adding this at the end of the arguments: `options=QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog`

Comment: Thanks musicamante, that's going to work for me (using ubuntu)